# Can't Hide Text View that contain values from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to hide Text View that has value from `SharedPreferences` but it wont work at all.

here is part of my Code That get Value from `SharedPreferences` and set it to the text view

```
private void CheckChart() {
        Order1 order1 = sharedPrefmanager.getInstance(getActivity()).GetOrder1();
        Order2 order2 = sharedPrefmanager.getInstance(getActivity()).GetOrder2();
        CartStatus CheckCartStats = sharedPrefmanager.getInstance(getActivity()).GetCartStatus();
        if (order1.getFoodName() == "null"){
            LinearLayoutCartOrder1.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else {
            if (CheckCartStats.getCart1Status() == "Full"){
                LinearLayoutCartOrder1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                Cart1Status = "full";
                //Fill the cart 1
                 order1 = sharedPrefmanager.getInstance(getActivity()).GetOrder1();
                //Food
                FoodCode = order1.getFoodCode();
                FoodName = order1.getFoodName();
                FoodCount = order1.getFoodCount();
                FoodTotalPrice = order1.getFoodTotalPrice();
                FoodType = order1.getFoodType();
                //Topping Name
                ToppingName1 = order1.getToppingName1();
                ToppingName2 = order1.getToppingName2();
                ToppingName3 = order1.getToppingName3();
                ToppingName4 = order1.getToppingName4();
                ToppingName5 = order1.getToppingName5();
                ToppingName6 = order1.getToppingName6();
                ToppingName7 = order1.getToppingName7();
                ToppingName8 = order1.getToppingName8();
                ToppingName9 = order1.getToppingName9();
                ToppingName10 = order1.getToppingName10();
                //Topping Price
                ToppingPrice1 = order1.getToppingPrice1();
                ToppingPrice2 = order1.getToppingPrice2();
                ToppingPrice3 = order1.getToppingPrice3();
                ToppingPrice4 = order1.getToppingPrice4();
                ToppingPrice5 = order1.getToppingPrice5();
                ToppingPrice6 = order1.getToppingPrice6();
                ToppingPrice7 = order1.getToppingPrice7();
                ToppingPrice8 = order1.getToppingPrice8();
                ToppingPrice9 = order1.getToppingPrice9();
                ToppingPrice10 = order1.getToppingPrice10();
                //Total Price
                TotalPrice = order1.getTotalPrice();

                //If the food is without type then Visibility to food type is gone
                if (FoodType == "null"){
                    TxtvCart1FoodCount.setText(FoodCount);
                    TxtvCart1FoodName.setText(FoodName);
                    TxtvCart1FoodPrice.setText(FoodTotalPrice);

                    TxtvCart1FoodType.setText(FoodType);
                    TxtvCart1FoodType.setVisibility(GONE);

                    TxtvCart1Topping1.setText(ToppingName1);
                    TxtvCart1Topping2.setText(ToppingName2);
                    TxtvCart1Topping3.setText(ToppingName3);
                    TxtvCart1Topping4.setText(ToppingName4);
                    TxtvCart1Topping5.setText(ToppingName5);
                    TxtvCart1Topping6.setText(ToppingName6);
                    TxtvCart1Topping7.setText(ToppingName7);
                    TxtvCart1Topping8.setText(ToppingName8);
                    TxtvCart1Topping9.setText(ToppingName9);
                    TxtvCart1Topping10.setText(ToppingName10);

                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice1.setText(ToppingPrice1);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice2.setText(ToppingPrice2);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice3.setText(ToppingPrice3);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice4.setText(ToppingPrice4);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice5.setText(ToppingPrice5);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice6.setText(ToppingPrice6);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice7.setText(ToppingPrice7);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice8.setText(ToppingPrice8);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice9.setText(ToppingPrice9);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice10.setText(ToppingPrice10);

                    TxtvCart1TotalPrice.setText(TotalPrice);
                    RemoveViewForUnusedTopping();
                }
                else {
                    TxtvCart1FoodCount.setText(FoodCount);
                    TxtvCart1FoodName.setText(FoodName);
                    TxtvCart1FoodPrice.setText(FoodTotalPrice);
                    TxtvCart1FoodType.setText(FoodType);

                    TxtvCart1Topping1.setText(ToppingName1);
                    TxtvCart1Topping2.setText(ToppingName2);
                    TxtvCart1Topping3.setText(ToppingName3);
                    TxtvCart1Topping4.setText(ToppingName4);
                    TxtvCart1Topping5.setText(ToppingName5);
                    TxtvCart1Topping6.setText(ToppingName6);
                    TxtvCart1Topping7.setText(ToppingName7);
                    TxtvCart1Topping8.setText(ToppingName8);
                    TxtvCart1Topping9.setText(ToppingName9);
                    TxtvCart1Topping10.setText(ToppingName10);

                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice1.setText(ToppingPrice1);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice2.setText(ToppingPrice2);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice3.setText(ToppingPrice3);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice4.setText(ToppingPrice4);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice5.setText(ToppingPrice5);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice6.setText(ToppingPrice6);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice7.setText(ToppingPrice7);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice8.setText(ToppingPrice8);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice9.setText(ToppingPrice9);
                    TxtvCart1ToppingPrice10.setText(ToppingPrice10);

                    TxtvCart1TotalPrice.setText(TotalPrice);
                    RemoveViewForUnusedTopping();


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the function to hide Unused Topping that have default value "null" from `SharedPreferences`

```
private void RemoveViewForUnusedTopping() {
        Order1 order1 = sharedPrefmanager.getInstance(getActivity()).GetOrder1();
        //Make Unused View Topping Dissapear
        //Topping 1
        if (order1.getToppingName1() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping1.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice1.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp1.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName1() != "null"){
            //Topping 1
            TxtvCart1Topping1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName2() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping2.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice2.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp2.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName2() != "null"){
            //Topping 2
            TxtvCart1Topping2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName3() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping3.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice3.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp3.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName3() != "null"){
            //Topping 3
            TxtvCart1Topping3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName4() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping4.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice4.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp4.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName4() != "null"){
            //Topping 4
            TxtvCart1Topping4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName5() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping5.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice5.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp5.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName5() != "null"){
            //Topping 5
            TxtvCart1Topping5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName6() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping6.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice6.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp6.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName6() != "null"){
            //Topping 6
            TxtvCart1Topping6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName7() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping7.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice7.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp7.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName7() != "null"){
            //Topping 7
            TxtvCart1Topping7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName8() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping8.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice8.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp8.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName8() != "null"){
            //Topping 8
            TxtvCart1Topping8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName9() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping9.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice9.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp9.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName9() != "null"){
            //Topping 9
            TxtvCart1Topping9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName10() == "null"){
            TxtvCart1Topping10.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice10.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp10.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else if(order1.getToppingName10() != "null"){
            //Topping 10
            TxtvCart1Topping10.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice10.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp10.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
        }

    }
```

No matter what I do the Unused topping wont `GONE`
I already try it to place the `RemoveViewForUnusedTopping()` function at button and pressed it still not working.
Is it really possible to hide `TextView` that has `SharedPreferences` Value set to it ?

Comment: `order1.getToppingName1() == "null" ` - this check for String value container in the object is "null" or not. To check if `getToppingName1()` is null(empty) use `order1.getToppingName1() == null` , without the quotes on null or use `TextUtils.isEmpty(order1.getToppingName1())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I already try this 
and change the def value in `SharedPreferences` to `null` then change the if to
`order1.getToppingName1() == null`

still not working, I'll try to use the `TextUtils.isEmpty(order1.getToppingName1())`

Comment: how about the 
`order1.getToppingName1() != null` with `TextUtils` ?

Comment: I've change the `==` to `Equals()` to this
 `order1.getToppingName10().equals(null)` and `!order1.getToppingName10().equals(null)` still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it after change to the `Equal()` and separate the if statement per `Textview` and changed it from  "null" to "none"

```
private void RemoveViewForUnusedTopping() {
        Order1 order1 = sharedPrefmanager.getInstance(getActivity()).GetOrder1();
        //Make Unused View Topping Dissapear
        //Topping 1
        if (TxtvCart1Topping1.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping1.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice1.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp1.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 1
            TxtvCart1Topping1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping2.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping2.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice2.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp2.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 2
            TxtvCart1Topping2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping3.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping3.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice3.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp3.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 3
            TxtvCart1Topping3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping4.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping4.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice4.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp4.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 4
            TxtvCart1Topping4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping5.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping5.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice5.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp5.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 5
            TxtvCart1Topping5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping6.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping6.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice6.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp6.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 6
            TxtvCart1Topping6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping7.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping7.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice7.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp7.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 7
            TxtvCart1Topping7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping8.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping8.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice8.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp8.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 8
            TxtvCart1Topping8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(TxtvCart1Topping9.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping9.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice9.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp9.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 9
            TxtvCart1Topping9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        if(TxtvCart1Topping10.getText().equals("none")){
            TxtvCart1Topping10.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice10.setVisibility(GONE);
            TxtvRp10.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else{
            //Topping 10
            TxtvCart1Topping10.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvCart1ToppingPrice10.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            TxtvRp10.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

    }
```